# Most efficient "get all reactions" method

Tags: discord.py

What is the most efficient way to access potentially 1000s of Reactions on a Discord Server?

Currently im using a @tasks.loop, and every 10 seconds Ill loop through all the messages im looking for Reactions on, then acess the message from Cached Messages.
I shouldnt be searching more than 100 Messages serverwide, though longterm this might be good to know an optimal option.

Ive got 3 different methods..

```
Message = await channel.fetch_message(x.id)

Message = discord.utils.get(client.cached_messages, id = x.id

@client.event
Async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
```

---

Im assuming the 2nd options

```
Discord.utils.get()
```

Is the quickest option?

I am developing a "mmorpg" and the primary form of user input will be reactions.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Also consider `wait_for` you can use that to wait for a reaction add on a specific message since you are making a game